# The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open c#

Tags: c#, database, ms-access

when i call this function in the timer its keep telling me that 
The connection was not closed the connection's current state is open

any help please...

```
    public static void Notify(string source, string query, ref OleDbConnection connection)
    {
        OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(query, connection);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();
            OleDbDataReader reader = command.ExecuteReader();

            while (reader.Read())
            {
                DateTime date = DateTime.Parse(reader[0].ToString());
                if (date.ToShortDateString() == DateTime.Now.ToShortDateString())
                {
                    DateTime time = DateTime.Parse(reader[1].ToString());
                    if (time.ToShortTimeString() ==DateTime.Now.ToShortTimeString())
                    {
                        string notification = source + " You have " + reader[2].ToString() + " at " + (time.ToLongTimeString()).ToString();

                        MessageBox.Show(notification, "Reminder", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

                    }
                }
            }

        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
```

Comment: at which line ?

Comment: Are you using the connection anywhere else? You provide it as ref-parameter so maybe it is not the only time you use it?

Comment: there is no error syntax ,, its just when the time is correct (equals the time .now)
its repeat the message for 60 sec more ,, 
its like telling me that i will stop when the time not correct

Comment: you are not checking if connection is already in open state, and opening it again causes this error

Comment: Mate i don't thinks that i have to check it ,, its already open ,, 
i need to close it ,, its not taking the finally statement

Comment: Also you're not disposing of your reader object or command object, both of which implement `IDisposable`.

Comment: And you don't need `ref` for your connection, you're not replacing the connection object.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the message says, your connection is already open. This means that you have already called

```
connection.Open();
```

somewhere before calling "Notify". Check your code to see if that's the case. Hope it helps.

Comment: guys ,, this function execute one time ,, and its goes to the Exception

Comment: try to debug your code. set a breakpoint to the line  where connection.Open() is called and see what happens. if the system shows an error when it reaches this line it means that the connection is already open as i mentioned above. if you need more information about it let me know